# How to change order barplot seaborn

Tags: python, bar-chart, seaborn

I have data as bellow

```
df = {u'Shkala' : [u'Wo', u' In', u'Ami', u'Tm', u'Re', u' Em', u'Leo', u' Ai', u' Sc',
    u'Ct', u' Cm', u'Py', u'Ac', u' Ie', u' Cs', u'Mp', u'Do', u' So',
    u'F/m', u'Lp', u' Sy', u' To', u' Gi', u' Sa', u' Wb', u' Sp', u' Fx'],
     u'Ves' :[   0.19110365,    0.27188837,    0.38561317,    1.05786403,
       1.92149932,    2.07645852,    2.54917337,    2.69292373,
       2.79209552,    3.69240049,    4.01010531,    4.42329527,
       4.47754007,    6.19537683,    6.29601984,    8.59108183,
       9.71862514,   10.30682861,   13.02674381,   13.65991585,
      14.02427094,   17.58381143,   25.72956782,   29.18101805,
      30.63714233,   63.52051974,  100.        ]}
```

I make

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.barplot(x="Shkala", y="Ves", data=df)
```

I get
[image]

I want re order that Fx become leftmost etc
I can do `sns.barplot(x="Shkala", y="Ves", data=df, order=['Fx', ......)` but it's very long 
Is there is a shorter way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reverse both lists in-place before plotting them:

```
df["Shkala"].reverse()
df["Ves"].reverse()
```

If you need the data to stay in its present form, create a duplicate dictionary to use or generate your order like so:

```
order = list(reversed(df["Shkala"]))
```

and pass that in as `order = order`

Comment: thanx @Gareth i haven't yet 15 point, when i get 15 i will vote

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)

Comment: Easier way: `df.iloc[::-1]`.